# Value is not updated onProgress for Range-seek-bar

Tags: java, android

### I am trying to use a two thumb seekbar

---

I am using **[This - PROJECT](http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)**

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private TextView txtStart,txtEnd;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtStart= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_starttime);
        txtEnd= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edt_endtime);
        // create RangeSeekBar as Integer range between 20 and 75
        RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(100, 1500, this);


        seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar,
                    Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                  // handle changed range values
                 String powerranger = "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue;
                 //Log.i(TAG, powerranger);
                 //textView1.setText(powerranger);
                 txtStart.setText(String.valueOf(minValue));
                 txtEnd.setText(String.valueOf(maxValue));

            }
        });

        // add RangeSeekBar to pre-defined layout
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(seekBar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

**RangeSeekBar.java** I have taken [from here](http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/)

Note:: I am not able to post complete code because code exceeds max characters allowed in site for **RangeSeekBar.java**

---

**Output**::

[image]

---

**Problem i am facing** ::

- During moving the thump it is not updating the textView with the
  value of range
- value is updated only after we remove the hand from the thumb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took a quick look at the code, and it seems that the `RangeSeekBar` class has a `notifyWhileDragging` property which you must set to `true` to get what you want (it is `false` by default).

Comment: Thanks ! ... I resolved it ..... But how can i increment it 100 by hundred ... Any inputs on this ?

Comment: You would need to do that manually. You need to read the value, round it to the closest 100, and write the value again.

Comment: i'm having a default selected value for this range seekbar but it can't be invalidate after set selected values any help?ofcourse it update while im true notifywhiledragging but i want it initally not when dragg..i think its buggy